# Working with specific listview item. (Items are loaded through usb as files)

Tags: c#, listview, c#-4.0

I am filling a listview based on the next code:

```
 public void leerArchivosUSB()
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("W:\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".docx") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".xls") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".xlsx") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".ppt") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".pptx") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".php"));
        listView2.LargeImageList = imageList1;
        listView2.View = View.LargeIcon;
        this.Controls.Add(this.listView2);
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"W:\");
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc") || s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".docx") || s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg") || s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpeg") || s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".xls") || s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".xlsx") || s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".ppt") || s.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".pptx")))
        {

            Icon iconForFile = SystemIcons.WinLogo;

            item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);
            iconForFile = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(file.FullName);

            // Check to see if the image collection contains an image
            // for this extension, using the extension as a key.
            if (!imageList1.Images.ContainsKey(file.Extension))
            {
                // If not, add the image to the image list.
                iconForFile = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(file.FullName);
                imageList1.Images.Add(file.Extension, iconForFile);
            }
            item.ImageKey = file.Extension;
            listView2.Items.Add(item);

        }

    }
```

And the list fills correctly. The things I am loading into it are files from a usb, with some filters.
After one item is selected, how can I load it, get the file name and path for displaying it in a label?